# How to store user's profile pictures in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to allow users to have profile pictures. They usually small in size, so I'm happy to have a constraint on the picture size.

What's the best way to store these in Firestore?

[Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) mention that **binary blob** data type is supported. However, I struggled to find any reference or example in the documentation.

Or, maybe I should be looking at [Uploading Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)?